# A few months old Xamarin Forms iOS project wont launch when debugging, stuck at "Building projectname.. (Debug iPhoneSimulator)"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am going to upgrade a few months old project but the project never launch when i try to debug it and it keeps getting stuck in an endless loop looking like this:

[image]

I can without any trouble launch/debug/build my recent projects but this one gives me trouble.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: It happens to be the "few months" where most bits (from Apple and Xamarin) have been updated, so if you don't update your tool chain I don't expect anything old would run without problems.

Comment: cancel build , restart visual studio, build again.